# Which materials to use to make exterior doors?

Tags: materials

***Context.***  Door size is about 1m wide and 2m tall, and environment is sunny, humid and hot climate.

***Question.*** What are the material options for the structure such that the door is durable?  I will then study the options as per my budget and pick one.

---

***My observation so far.*** One ancient option is to use exterior-durable wood species.  But I think nowadays this option is becoming more of a luxury for achieving natural looks.  I'm not sure if my observation is correct.

Other options include:  using metals (which metals?) and uPVC.  Not sure

As for the finish, I can finish them with any material.  E.g. even if I go with steel structure, I can still nail/screw/glue wood-sheets on it to make it look like wood.  Although I'm not sure how durable this option will be compared to a full solid wooden door.

---

This is a broader version of [that](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13136/how-to-pick-the-right-timber-for-external-doors) as [that](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13136/how-to-pick-the-right-timber-for-external-doors) is limited to wood species, while this exploring material options beyond wood.

Comment: What are the oldest outer doors made of?

Comment: @SolarMike - Oldest in history? I guess goat skin or tree leaves.  But how is this relevant?  New materials keep getting engineered to enhance life and lower cost at the same time.

Comment: So if "new" materials are so good, why are recent concrete buildings being demolished?

Comment: @SolarMike - Because progress is not mistake-free.  They're still orders of magnitude stronger than ancient mud houses.  Plus many other economical factors.  If you can't say something useful, don't post noise here.

Comment: You can make a door out of literally any structural material.  Just to take residential doors as an example, regular softwood (paint it), fancy hardwood, plastic, steel, fiberglass-over-wood.  Expand to commercial doors: aluminum probably a main one.  "Most durable" isn't a very good spec, but a solid stainless steel door will probably last for centuries if the hinges and frame hold up.

Comment: @TigerGuy - Can lacquer/sealer function as a paint replacement for softwood?  Will it protect against warping?

Comment: yes, people build houses out of softwood all the time, it needs to stay painted to prevent water damage.  People use sealers on decks in the US, I'm guessing natural wood homes use something similar.

Comment: I think for your region, it is more of an interest to pay attention to the effectiveness in sealing and block out the heat and humidity. Your door might stay for 100 years, the sealer usually won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exterior doors Have to be able to resist elements, be fire-rated (usually 20 minutes, but it could vary depending on type and location), and tolerate a high frequency of traffic and abuse of getting banged by large items, furnuture and appliances pushed through them.

Traditionally they were made solid-core from

- Alder.
- Poplar.
- Cedar.
- Rustica Red Oak.
- Cherry.
- White Pine.
- Hickory.
- Mahogany

Here in the US, the price of hardwood has gone up drastically, so many are using composite construction with a faux finish of look of some species.

Now there are doors made of hard particle boards and clad with sheets of metal or PVC.

we need to balance cost VS durability, functionality, and esthetics.